# Getting tag values in XML separately

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<categories>
    <category1 name="Music">
        <file>tabla.txt</file>
        <file>sitar.txt</file>
    </category1>

    <category2 name="Documents">
        <file>OCD1.txt</file>
        <file>OCD2.txt</file>
    </category2>

    <category3 name="Movies">
            <file>Thisistheend.txt</file>
        <file>TheInternship.txt</file>
    </category3>
</categories>
```

I am using the following query to get the  tag value:

```
q = from x in doc.Descendants() where (x.Attributes().Count()>0
&& (x.Attribute("name").Value == key) select x;
```

But the `<File>` tag values are getting appended. When I am trying to display the values using for each then for eg: the `<file>` tag value for "Documents" is being displayed as "OCD1.txtOcd2.txt" in a ListView box. How do I get these two values separated in my LINQ query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the file contents using a `SelectMany` query. In query syntax you can accomplish this by adding an extra from/select query on the matching category.

```
var query = from x in doc.Descendants()
            where (string)x.Attribute("name") == key
            from file in x.Elements("file")
            select file.Value;
```

Also notice that I updated the filtering to check for the `name` attribute directly. You can avoid checking for attribute count. It's unnecessary and doesn't guarantee the existence of the `name` attribute. If you're trying to guard against a missing `name` attribute then you can cast the attribute, which will return `null` if it doesn't exist. I've done this using this bit of code: `(string)x.Attribute("name") == key`

Answer (score 1):

Using a Lambda Expression approach to the LINQ query this would accomplish your needs as well.

```
var q = doc.Descendants()
           .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == key)
           .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("file"))
           .Select(x => x.Value);
```